# Having trouble with hexdump program in C

Tags: c, hexdump

I can't seem to get any characters to print, in fact, it seems like the program won't read *any* file correctly, as all the hex values are zeros when I give it a file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <argp.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

static error_t parse_opt(int key, char *arg, struct argp_state *state);
static void dump_hex(char *f, size_t l);

static struct argp_option options[] = {
    {"filepath",    'f', "PATH",    0, "uses filepath provided by user" },
    { 0 }
};

struct arguments {
    char *path;
    /* int *column_size; */
};

static error_t parse_opt(int key, char *arg, struct argp_state *state) {

    struct arguments *arguments = state->input;

    switch(key) {
        case 'f':
            arguments->path = arg;
            break;

        default:
            return ARGP_ERR_UNKNOWN;
        }

    return 0;
}

static struct argp argp = { options, parse_opt, NULL, NULL };

static void dump_hex(char *f, size_t l) {

    FILE *fd;
    size_t i;
    unsigned char *b = (unsigned char *)malloc(16 * sizeof(unsigned char));

    memset(b, 0, 16 * sizeof(unsigned char));

    if((fd = fopen(f, "r"))) {
        for(i = 0; i <= l; i++) {
            if((i % 8) == 0) {
                if(i != 0) {
                    printf("| %s\n", b);
                }
                /* print the offset */
                printf("%05lx: ", i);
            }
            /* check if ASCII is printable */
            b[i % 16] = isprint(b[i]) ? b[i] : '.';

            /* print ASCII */
            printf("%02x ", b[i]);
        }

        /* print remaining ASCII */
        printf("| %s\n", b);
    }

    fclose(fd);
    free(b);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct arguments arguments;
    struct stat sb;
    off_t size;

    arguments.path = "-";

    argp_parse(&argp, argc, argv, 0, 0, &arguments);

    stat(arguments.path, &sb);
    size = sb.st_size;

    dump_hex(arguments.path, size);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output I receive upon giving it an argument to a binary:

```
./hexdump --filepath=/tmp/a.out

212d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ................
212d8: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ................
212e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ................
212e8: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ................
212f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ................
212f8: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ................
Segmentation fault
```

Also, any tips on making the code a bit more concise would be very beneficial.

Comment: I recommend you use `fp` for a file pointer (`FILE *fp`), reserving `fd` for a file descriptor (`int fd`).  I recommend you separate file opening and closing from hex dumping; pass an open file stream (file pointer) to the dex dump function.  This avoids problems with "how to deal with `-` as a file name" — you just pass `stdin` as the file stream.  Note that if you fail to open a file, you still `fclose()` it; this is a recipe for segmentation faults.  Check your memory allocation, too, though I grant you it is unlikely to fail. **Where do you read the file?** I see no code reading the file?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I used `fd = fopen(f, "r")` to open the file and I iterate through it with the following loop.

Comment: @redoes: This code does only opens the file for read access. But you're not reading aynthing. You have to use `fread()` for that.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Am I not reading through the file when I iterate through it?

Comment: `fopen()` opens the file for reading.  There is no `getc()`, `fgetc()`, `fread()`, or similar function call to actually read the data from the opened file.

Comment: @redoes: You're aren't iterate through the file just with using a `for` loop in your code.

Comment: If the length of the file is not a multiple of 8 bytes, you will need to print some padding in place of the missing 1-7 hex values before printing the string.  You also need to add a terminal null.  You should only have 8 dots (at most) on the RHS given your current structure.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are getting zeros is that you don't read the content of your file and `b` is initialized with `0x00`. Your just opening and closing the file.

Another problem (this could be the reason for the segmentation fault) is that `b` has a size of 16 bytes. On some places you are using `i % 16` but not on all (on some places you use `i` directly). You should definitely check this.